How to protect .env file
I've hosted a node js app on cpanel as example.com but the problem is in my node directory having .env file and if I try to visit example.com/.env this file get downloaded. So how to secure .env file?
I tried to add htaccess
<Files "env">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

Even I've changed file permission to 0600. But it doesn't work.

You cant usually see the files that are part of a node js app unless you specifically publish those files using static. Makes me think you have placed the node js app files in the root folder of a webserver

Thank you, you're right. I have deployed the Node.js app in the root directory of the web server.

Basicly there are 4 options:

Add this code in .htaccess:
<FilesMatch ".env">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all


Move the file outside the public directory: Move the .env file outside of the public directory (e.g., public_html) to prevent it from being accessible via the web server.

Use a process manager: Use a process manager like PM2 to manage your Node.js application. PM2 can automatically handle environment variables and keep them separate from your codebase.

Use environment variables in your code: Instead of hard-coding sensitive information in your code, use environment variables. This way, you can easily manage and secure sensitive data without modifying your code.


